# ViewPager for custom View with canvas objects

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-canvas

I'm searching for a solution to implement the ViewPager for a custom View. There are a lot of tutorials for ViewPager which inflates xml layouts, but I couldn't find an example with custom views. 
My custom View class draws multiple objects (circles with text around it) on a canvas.
[image] The objects can be moved and scaled by implementing the OnTouchListener. 
The objects are generated dynamically ( the text comes from an ArrayList)

In the Activity I instantiate a new View with different parameters:

```
this.mRenderCircleView = new RenderCircleView(this, resultList, showDemo);
```

The resultList holds an `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` with the circles to draw in the RenderCircleView. 
I want to implement the ViewPager in the case, if there are a lot of circle items in the ArrayList ( > 5 ) and due to performance issues it would be bad to create and load all views previously. So I thing the best choice is the FragmentStatePagerAdapter. This should be the better solution for interactive content.

But I couldn't figure out how it works. The count of Fragments would depend on the size of the given ArrayList divided by the count of elements which should be drawn in the RenderCircleView. For example the ArrayList size is 20 and 5 circleObjects should be drawn on each page, then I need 4 pages (fragments).

What is the easiest way to use the ViewPager in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, every entries in the resultList represents one circle. 
It is indeed a good idea to use the FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

You could solve it like this:

Your Activity hosts a layout with the ViewPager object. The ViewPager hosts a list of Fragments, let's name them CircleFragment. The CircleFragment has a layout with a RenderCircleView.

When instantiating the CircleFragment, put the ArrayList in the Fragment.setArguments(Bundle) and retrieve those when the view of the CircleFragment is inflated. (see the edit about putting the arraylist)

In your Activity: create the amount of CircleFragments you need and put them into the FragmentStatePagerAdapter you'll use for the ViewPager.

**EDIT** (about putting `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` in `Fragment.setArguments(Bundle)`)

An ArrayList implements the Serializable interface. If you look at a Bundle, you can put a Serializable in it! Java takes care of serializing it. Piece of cake :)

[`Bundle.putSerializable(String key, Serializable value)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putSerializable%28java.lang.String,%20java.io.Serializable%29)
[`Bundle.getSerializable(String key)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#getSerializable%28java.lang.String%29)

**EDIT 2** (about using `Fragment.onCreateView()`)

The inflater is there just in case (!) you need it. Just leave the inflater for what it is, instantiate the `RenderCircleView` (like you do in your original code) and return that in `Fragment.onCreateView`. You might like to wrap a `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout` around it for better control of the position of your `RenderCircleView`.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want to achieve. I'll try to implement this and post my the result here. I did'nt know that I can use setArguments to retrieve the data.

Comment: How is it possible to put arguments of the Type ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>, Bundle doesn't support this Type.

Comment: Ok, thanks! But how do I use the `inflater` in this context, in the `onCreateView` of the `Fragment` class? The inflater parameters only matches the id of a layout xml and not a custom View `RenderCircleView`. I'm following this [tutorial](http://www.truiton.com/2013/05/android-fragmentstatepageradapter-example/)

Comment: The inflater is there just in case (!) you need it. Just leave the inflater for what it is, instantiate the `RenderCircleView` (like you do in your original code) and return that in `Fragment.onCreateView`. You might like to wrap a `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout` around it for better control of the position of your `RenderCircleView`.

Comment: Awesome... finally it's working. Thanks a lot! I was struggling to get the inflater working... But I think due to the ViewPager it isn't possible to add a popup Dialog to the screen when touching a specific object!?

Comment: Nice! :) Glad it's working. About the dialog: I'm sure that's possible, but I don't know how. I think it's better to start a new question on that topic.

Comment: I could solve the problem by using DialogFragment. Before I just created a new dialogbuilder, without a fragment-container around it.